# How to get the sequence of numbers back after random number generation

Tags: java, random

Am in the middle of an encryption algorithm, I have written the code to randomly shuffle a series of numbers in java. 
Here is the code:

```
public class permute6 {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int arr[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80};// Original Array

    System.out.println("Original array is" );
    for(int k = 0; k<arr.length;k++ )
        System.out.print(arr[k] +  "\t" );
    System.out.println(" ");

    int max = arr.length - 1;
    int min = 0;
    int rnum;
    int larr = arr.length - 1;
    int[] parr = new int[arr.length];// to store the permuted array 
    int flag = 0;// 'flag' to flag the recurring number
    int plen = parr.length - 1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
    {
             rnum = (rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min);// roll for the     
                    random number
             parr[plen] = arr[rnum];
             arr[rnum] = arr[larr];

             larr--;// to reduce the size of the original array
             plen--;// to make the parr to act like a stack
             max--;
    }

    System.out.println("Permuted array is" );
    for(int k = 0; k<arr.length;k++ )
        System.out.print(parr[k] +  "\t" );

    System.out.println();
  }
  }
```

If the initial array is {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80}

then one of the shuffled result is

50  20  30  10  60  80  70  40

Now if I transmit this array, then how to get back the original sequence at the destination side? What can be done to keep track of the sequence?
What is missing here....Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Can't you just store the things in the array into another array?

Comment: You mean...the initial numbers and the shuffled numbers in separate array?? That is what I have done...the initial array is in 'arr' and the final array is in 'parr'... getting back the original sequence is my problem...any suggestions??

Comment: What I am trying to say is that make one array for the destination side (I don't understand what you mean by the destination side actually) and copy the contents of `parr[]` in that array which will remain on the destination side. If you think that my suggestion is wrong, there is a huge possibility that I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Assume the array 'arr' is to be sent secretly ..so I'll perform a permutation on the array and I'll get 'parr'. This parr is transmitted...Actually this 'parr' is the permutated 'arr'. So I've to get back 'arr' from 'parr'. The order of the initail array is lost in the permuted array...how to get back the numbers in the original order???

Comment: what I am saying is, copy `arr[]` into another array `carr[]` and then permutate `arr[]` into `parr[]`. Then you will have the original order saved in the destination system. and `parr[]` can be transmitted secretly aswell.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time Sir..if carr[ ] is intercepted then..the original data will be revealed right??? I need to retrieve back the arr[ ] from parr[ ]. How can this be done??

Comment: Are you transmitting data over sockets?

Comment: No not at all... No socket programming. Just for the experimental purpose; both the sender and the receiver are considered to be the same machine. I just want to know how to get back the original array after the permutation.

Comment: So what do you mean by `carr[]` is intercepted?

Comment: Here .... I am not at all talking about sending the original array. carr[ ] which is the copy of the original according to you is not at all in the picture. Assume I have arr[ ] and I have done permutation on the arr[ ] so I got the parr[ ]. Now from the parr[ ] I have to get back the original array that is arr[ ]. Since am doing random permutation over arr[ ] , I don't know how to keep track of the original sequence .

Answer (score 0):

You can submit two arrays to destination parr and temp;
parr: [50 20 30 10 60 80 70 40]
and 
temp(It is basically difference of permuted array from original e.g. parr-arr):

like {50, 20, 30, 10, 60, 80, 70, 40} - {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80}
temp = {40,0,0,-30,10,20,0,-40}

Now,
At destination again get difference of parr and temp "parr-temp"
  {50, 20, 30, 10, 60, 80, 70, 40} - {40,0,0,-30,10,20,0,-40}
= {10,20,30,10-(-30),50,60,70,40-(-40)}

You will get your original sequence without sending original array at destination

Another solution came into mind related to previous one but it will avoid transferring two arrays to destination. Merge both temp and parr into a single array say newArr = {50,40,20,0,30,0,10,-30,60,10,80,20,70,0,40,-40}
and at destination just subtract each element from the next element and you will get your original array using only one array.

Comment: Thats a great idea....Thank you so much....I'll implement it and surely get back to you.....

Comment: Thanks Rohit, please accept the answer if you like it.